# my divs are hidden under the others because of position absolute and 0 height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with some cards I've made with Bootstrap. Here's the code:

```css
formacion {
    color: white;
    position: relative;
}

.formacion .puesto {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.formacion .puesto img{
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.formacion .empresa {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 52px;
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    color: #000;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
<h2>Formación<br><small>Experiencias académicas destacadas</small></h2>
<div class="col-md-12 capsula-formacion">
    <div class="formacion row" style="background-color: #8224e3">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 puesto">
            <img src="http://jdlcgarcia.es/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/Captura-de-pantalla-2016-10-17-a-las-14.50.26-150x150.png" alt=" @ " title=" @ " class="img-circle img-responsive center-block">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <h3 class="text-center">Ingeniero en informatica</h3>
        </div>


        <div class="col-sm-9 empresa" style="background-color: #e688ff">
            <h4 class="text-center col-sm-offset-3">Universidad<br><small></small></h4>
            <div class="row-fluid text-center col-sm-offset-3">
                01-09-2004 - 01-04-2011 linea1
                <br> linea2
                <br> linea3
                <br>
            </div>
            <div class="row-fluid">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12 capsula-formacion">
    <div class="formacion row" style="background-color: #81d742">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 puesto">
            <img src="http://jdlcgarcia.es/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/Captura-de-pantalla-2016-10-17-a-las-15.41.22-150x150.png" alt=" @ " title=" @ " class="img-circle img-responsive center-block">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <h3 class="text-center">Curso 1</h3>
        </div>


        <div class="col-sm-9 empresa" style="background-color: #e5ffa6">
            <h4 class="text-center col-sm-offset-3">La institución<br><small></small></h4>
            <div class="row-fluid text-center col-sm-offset-3">
                01-10-2016 - 31-10-2016 linea1
                <br> linea2
                <br> linea3
                <br>
            </div>
            <div class="row-fluid">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This code makes my divs look like this:

[image]

When they have to show like this (achieved by adding a fixed height to .capsula-formacion, but I don't want to put it because some of the divs could be longer than others):

[image]

I have always the same problem when I'm using absolute positioning so I'm  assuming I'm doing it wrong. Which's the way to achieve my desired layout? Thank you in advance!!

Comment: That's how absolute positioning works. When an item is positioned absolutely, it no long affects things like flow and sizing on ancestor and sibling elements.

Comment: it's the attribute of absolute positioning. make sure you each div ends.

Comment: @Ouroborus thank you for your comment. There's a way to do so without absolute positioning?

Comment: @vish_youtube yeah, all my divs close well

Answer (score 0):

Don't put absolute position in content div. You can manage image by position absolute.

You can set image by minus position and also you can set image width and height.

In responsive view you can manage image width and height by break point(Media query css).